# *ngFor two values from array

Tags: arrays, foreach, typescript, angular

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Us4AUk39xPmDM3y0f2lH?p=preview)

I'm trying to format data in angular using pipes. for the headers and fields names I use an array passed in from typescript, it works very nice. problem is when I try to pass in the field type from the same array, angular doesn't accept it.

the error is:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '[' at column 23 in [{{tran[col.field] | tran[col.type]}}] in Transaction@27:79
            ("et tran of _trans"><td class="text-navy" *ngFor="let col of cols">[ERROR ->]
    {{tran[col.field] | tran[col.type]}}</td>
```

Typescript  Code:

```
  private cols;
  this.cols = [
            { field: "DateCreated", header: "Date", type: "date" },
            { field: "Name", header: "Customer", type: "string" },
            { field: "Amount", header: "Amount", type : "money" }
                    ];
```

Angular2 Code:

```
    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.header}}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let tran of _trans">
                                        <td class="text-navy"
                               *ngFor="let col of cols">
                               {{tran[col.field]
                               | col.type <--- here's the problem!}}
                               </td>
                               </tr>
                               </tbody>
```

EDIT: I just tried to {{tran[col.field] + col.type }} that gives no error, it displays my datatype name together with the value. problem begins when I put the | in the middle..

Comment: Why not pass the whole `col` object to the pipe? Then do type-checks there....

Comment: wish I would know how do to it... can you please give a little sample?

Comment: Here's an example of passing an object to the pipe - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5AVp7TqI2vnjt7yDTxe?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your effort in creating the plonker for me, However I can't seem to find how to apply it to my situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

If you want to provide pipes by data, something like this should work:

```
<td class="text-navy"
  *ngFor="let col of cols">
  {{col.type.tranform(tran[col.field])}}>
```

**original**

You are missing the pipe name and parameters to the pipe are added with `:`

```
{{value | pipe:param}}
```

This also works

```
{{value | pipe:param[propName]}}
```

Comment: I'm not missing it, I supplied it in the array and it should load the same as the data loads.

Comment: You can't pass a pipe from an array. The pipe name needs to be statically added to your template, at least if you want to use the `| pipe` syntax. A pipe is just code and you always can call out to code from bindings.

Comment: Ohh that's exactly my problem.. is there any work around? I don't want to list all fields in the template.. its much cleaner with a ngFor on a list of columns... Still I need to format some of the columns.

Comment: Thanks the error changed now to: self.context.$implicit.type.tranform is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_Transaction3.detectChangesInternal

Comment: If you could provide a Plunker that demonstrates what you're actually trying to accomplish this would be easier to investigate. For example what does `tran[col.type]` return exactly. In the Plunker editor the `new` button provides an Angular2 TS RC.1 template.